# Use allure report in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, allure

I am trying to publish allure report on azure devops but i got that error on generate the report task :
`##[warning]Failed to publish test run data: System.ArgumentException: Unknown test runner`

In my baseconf.js the runner: `'local'`,

Where is my mistake. should i change the runner to remote and how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Alexa, Could you share the build definition and detail log here? By the way, you are using the task Generate Allure Report to publish allure report, right?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT That is my build definition and the error. i have tried with publish test result task but nothing happen again:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG929.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MRLs.png

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue And when I click on the Allure report page, I get the error 404.

[image]

This should be a issue with the extension Allure Test Reports, we recommend that you raise this issue to [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/issues), they will investigate the issue and help us solve it.

In addition, It seems that they are working on a second version, you could also check this [page](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2).

Comment: i don't have error 404 just the test results  are not available

Comment: the problem is that error : ##[warning]Failed to publish test run data: System.ArgumentException: Unknown test runner   how to change that configuration with something different than local